# XCode linker not finding framework or some libraries within the framework built via cocoapod

Tags: cocoapods

I just moved from manual to CocoaPods.  The first thing I tried was Urban Airship.  I got it all compiling but I get the following linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UAConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UAirship", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeScreenViewCtr.o
      objc-class-ref in MyProfileViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my pods build settings screenshot showing it's supposedly building the Urban Airship framework.

[image: build settings]

My XCode file is opened to the xcworkspace file not the xcodeproj.

Now I don't know if I'm supposed to add the Urban Airship framework my Build Phases "Link Binary With Libraries".  It seems to have created a pod named after my own App, should that be in the "Link Binary With ...".  What should be listed under the "Frameworks" folder and under the yellow "Pods" folder in my main file / folder navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured it out.  "$(inherited)" was missing from my "Framework Search Paths" of my build target.  I did the "pod setup" command but it apparently forgot to set up my Framework Search Paths correctly.

Detailed answer:

Set up your Framework Search Path
[image: Framework Search Path]

Add the cocoapods framework to your Build Phases, but do NOT add that Pod_your_app_name.framework
[image]

In your main navigator: Do not attempt to add anything related to the cocoapod Framework e.g. AirshipKit to your yellow "Pods" folder, but it should appear in your yellow "Frameworks" folder.

If you really search for the inner working of CocoaPods, you'll find that your cocoa pods frameworks get built deep in your ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData directory.  Various compile variables point over that direction.